# Spring integration : handle a File given in arguments

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, arguments, spring-integration

I have an existing Spring Integration app, which handle files coming from FTP with InboundChannelAdapter. I want to plug Spring boot to this app to use it now like this :

`java -jar app.jar <filetohandlepath>`

So, the application start with this command, and stop at the end of the treatment. But my question is how can I run my existing channels (`ServiceActivator`) to give this file to handle ?

- I can use an `InboundChannelAdapter`, but I think the `poller` can be a problem
- Maybe a `Gateway` ? But I don't think this can be a solution
- Or I need to build and send a Message manually ?

What about Spring Boot, to handle the argument ? I need to build the message into the main method, or in an other class with a scan ?

I just need to know the best way to design my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FTP Inbound Channel Adapter polls remote file to local files and sends them as payload of messages into some channel for the mentioned Service Activator. Of course you can send message manually to the same channel with the payload accepted by that Service Activator subscriber. Yes, you can use `@MessagingGateway` to separate Messaging concern from your code. Or you can just rely on the `MessagingTemplate` and its `convertAndSend()` API. Any convenient way for you is acceptable: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

As for Spring Boot and command line arguments, you definitely can take a look into the `CommandLineRunner`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner

Comment: I don't want to use `InboundChannelAdapter` anymore, I just need to send a message a the begining and stop the app. But now, with spring boot, everything is load with the context, and then the app i run, that's why I think I prefer to use the `MessagingTemplate`, it seems easier. But how can I run it ? I mean, it's possible to make bean, or load a class in the context who build this `MessagingTemplate` ? Because I tried, and it return a `NullPointerExceptions`

Comment: Right, you can create a `MessagingTemplate` bean and inject it into the the `CommandLineRunner`.

Comment: Thanks, that's whas exactly what I needed ! But my errorChannel seems not working, is that normal when we launch the app like this ?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a related to the subject question. If you send message manually, you should expect an exception to catch. Indeed no any error channels are involved here already.

Comment: But I've already an "errorChannel", with an "exception-type-router" who handle exceptions, so it can be called if there is an Exception if I use the `MessagingTemplate` ?

Comment: That's not clear from this perspective. If you have `errorChannel` on the `InboundChannelAdapter`, there is no such a hook on the `MessagingTemplate`. You should consider to look into the `@MessagingGateway` instead.

Comment: With this way I can send a message only one time before to stop the app, and I can handle the `errorChannel` ?

Comment: That's correct. As far as your `errorChannel` doesn't shift to another thread. Therefore everything is going to happen on the caller thread.